# Flash video player for AVI files (free for commercial use)

Tags: flash

Are there any Flash video players, free for commercial use, that are able to playback AVI files? JW Player is out of the question because in the readme it states that use by a corporation is considered commercial use and needs a different license.

Comment: This is a duplicate, I'm sure...

Comment: Strobe Media Playback. Bsd license. Directly from adobe. .... docs suck at this point though.... player is pretty good though...  http://sourceforge.net/adobe/smp/wiki/Home/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Flash does not natively handle the AVI container format. It can only play back the two forms of FLVs (Soresen Spark and ON2 v6) and h264 video in a few different containers (MP4, MOV) that conform to some specific requirements.

As far as I know, no one has ported AVI reading code to ActionScript. Technically it should be possible, but there's a good chance Flash simply wouldn't be fast to handle video of any real quality.

You can transcode AVIs to formats that Flash can playback using a variety of tools including ffmpeg.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like I'm the only one who knows about this: http://flowplayer.org/

It's free for commercial use (GPL 3), has a ton of features including the ability to splice in commercials.

Comment: Does it play .avi files? Don't think so.

Comment: Does anything play AVI files in Flash? I suppose I could edit the comment to suggest that the file needs to be converted first. *shrug*

Comment: The poster asked if anyone knew of a player that plays AVI files. Flowplayer does NOT: http://flowplayer.org/docs/encoding.html

Answer (score 2):

Strobe Media Playback. Bsd license. Directly from adobe. .... docs suck at this point though.... player is pretty good though...  http://sourceforge.net/adobe/smp/wiki/Home/

Answer (score 1):

Check the [JQuery Media Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/media/)

> The jQuery Media Plugin supports unobtrusive conversion of standard markup into rich media content. It can be used to embed virtually any media type, including Flash, Quicktime, Windows Media Player, Real Player, MP3, Silverlight, PDF and more, into a web page. The plugin converts an element (usually an ) into a  which holds the object, embed or iframe tags neccessary to render the media content.