# Web AVI Player?

Tags: javascript, html, video, avi

I'm looking to play AVI files in a web browser however I can't seem to find a decent tool to do so.

The basic WMP object embed is what I'm using right now but it doesn't really do what I'd like it to do, and I can't really implement JavaScript into it. (AFAIK I can't. I done a little digging and that's the conclusion I came to)

I've also tried DivX though I don't really like it. It has adverts, and I've no idea if JavaScript can be included either.

AFAIK Flash doesn't support AVI playback at all.
Does anyone know of any player at all that can play AVI files on the web, which I could possibly integrate some kind of JavaScript in (or has an API)?
Just a thought too, but would Java itself have anything like this?

The player also needs to be able to source the files like this:
`file:\\Network-PC-Name\avi\avifile.avi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flowplayer is recommended by this post:
[Flash video player for AVI files (free for commercial use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163083/flash-video-player-for-avi-files-free-for-commercial-use)

not sure about the file:\ source, as that's on your local machine and could be refused by the browser for security reasons

Comment: Flowplayer doesn't seem to find the file. So I tried copying an AVI to the same directory as flowplayer, and it gave me the same error, saying it can't find it.

Comment: it could be for a security reason:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537183(v=vs.85).aspx#local

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is [WebChimera](http://www.webchimera.org/), there's no doubt about it. It has the [most complex JS API](http://wiki.webchimera.org/WebChimera_Wiki) ever made for web video, and it supports all file types.. it also supports "file:///" (for links like `file:///C:/avi/avifile.avi`).

It is open source and has no advertising. And the best part is that everything inside the player is editable, so you can skin it, add buttons and even add entirely new features to it with mostly just JavaScript. :)

**Update**

As you mentioned you need it to connect to `file:///Network-PC-Name/avi/avifile.avi`, this tells me you need this for some Local / Private / LAN use.

In this case, I think the best solution for you is to use WebChimera with [Node-Webkit](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/), as it will also give you a JS API based server environment.

WebChimera Player is already ported to NW for Windows and Mac:
https://github.com/jaruba/WebChimeraPlayerNW

On Windows, just [download the package](https://github.com/jaruba/WebChimeraPlayerNW/archive/master.zip), and run nw.exe. To customize just edit the html pages. For Mac, just follow the instructions in the Readme.md.

The great part about using it like this, is that it already has the plugin embedded in the app, so you won't even need to install the plugin for the player to work.

The only thing I can't be fully sure of, is if `Network-PC-Name` can even be accessed through the `file:///` protocol in it's normal usage. But this would still be possible anyway as you could [map the network drive](http://www.howtogeek.com/118452/how-to-map-network-drives-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows/), and you can even map it programatically (with only JavaScript!) by using the [child process exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to run the necessary command. (`child_process` is built in node-webkit natively)

Comment: I'll check this beast out! Thanks. I'll mark your answer as the correct answer if it does what I need.